# YII2 Project foldertransferred from one pc to another with PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException Array to string conversion

Tags: php, yii2

[image]

[image]

[image]

The screenshots above are the errors. I have every configurations needed. The version of php installed and the xampp contol panel as well. Followed the guide too. The yii project folder is from my co-worker and I intend to run the system in my pc so I needed to copy the whole file in my xampp\htdocs. But everytime I enter the login details, it always shows the error show in the image below. Please help me figure this out. My php version installed is 7.4.27 and xampp control panel version 3.3.0

Comment: Did you migrate the database too?

Comment: Did you connected your test db and imported it to your loc environment?

Comment: Because it looks like it does not pass login